# Is there any R package to create a beautiful pie chart like disk analyser' output chart?

Tags: r

Beautiful pie chart with daisyDisk
[image]

Comment: Try putting more effort into your question and tell us what you have already tried to find.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example from the help page of `?radial.pie` of the `plotrix` package:

```
library(plotrix)
pie2<-list(0:3,1:6,2:5,1:4,0:7,4:8,2:9,0:1,0:4)
radial.pie(pie2,labels=letters[2:10])
```

[image]

Very similar results can also be obtained with the `ggplot2` library by combining its `coord_polar()` and `geom_histogram()` functions.

See the examples in `?ggplot2::coord_polar` for more information.